# Cannot get Selenium to access a certain class

Tags: python, java, selenium, automation, selenium-chromedriver

I am just working with Selenium to automate some simple tasks at work. I am unable to get it to access this class:

`<a class="qx-nav-name qx-nav-ellipsis" href="javascript:openInIFrame('iamain', 'company_migration.phtml%3f.sess%3dZcv4vINlw4RYZSvCGO7K_wW_hFllTmXLo2dmelAVWGUrwhjuyvEYo4RY%26.ifmod%3dco%26.done%3dY5F7ZfgEOSSVJqglLXtQhgAAAAw28%26eSecReq%3dS0VZX1NFQzpDUENvc2xicXhiYlN6Z1UxL280SjBjYjR0UW1yZ2xVOHFTRU1PQTRjVi9rPQ..%26.op%3d258&amp;.menuItemRefNo=0')">Import data</a>`

This is the code I am using
`

```
driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, '.qx-nav-name.qx-nav-ellipsis').click()
```

`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using below code

```
driver.find_element(By.Link_Text, 'Import data').click()
```